# ApplicationSettings reset when end-client install an update

Tags: c#

I had C# WinForm on .NET Framework 4, it has ApplicationSettings which has default values.  When the app is installed at the end-client, the default value(s) are set base on workstations criteria.  Every time the end-client install the updated version of the application, those local settings are gone and it get backs to the default values.

Comment: "default value(s) are set base on workstations criteria" Sounds like you just need to do that every time the application is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the local application settings modified after install is in a version-specific directory.  There exists an [`ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade(v=vs.110).aspx) method that will upgrade the applications settings on a new version, from a prior version.

You should call this once after install of the new version.  To do this only once, one way is to add an User setting (call it `UpgradeRequired`) with a default value of `true`.  If the value is `true`, call `Upgrade()`, set `UpgradeRequired` to `false` and save the settings.  For example:

```
  if (Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
  {
     Settings.Default.Upgrade();
     Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
     Settings.Default.Save();
  }
```